# Search array and return missing values

Tags: php, arrays

I use this code to check if values exist in an array:

```
if (!in_array(array("Product code","Price","Supplier","Cost Price"), $data)) {
        die("You are missing fields");
     }
```

Works fine but I would like it to return the value that does not exist so if th array was  this:

```
$data = array("Price","Supplier","Cost Price");
```

PHP would return "Product code is not in array"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array_diff to find difference in multiple arrays comparison.

```
    $array1 = array("a" => "Product code","Price","Supplier","Cost Price");
if (!in_array($array1, $data)) {
        die("You are missing :" . print_r(array_diff($array1, $data)));
     }
```

From the PHP manual:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);     /* This will print: BLUE */
?>
```

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **[array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)** -Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

```
<?php
  $array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
  $array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
  $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
   print_r($result);
?>
```

or use `in_array` like

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

to check all array you can use something like

```
foreach($array as $val){
if (in_array($val, $os)) {
        echo "Got Irix";
    }

}else{
     //show error

}
```

Comment: `array_diff` is clearly the better way to do this, index checks are not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php ; with these functions, you can check what's the difference (or common part) of two arrays and iterate through the differences (or common parts) to tell the user exactly what's missing/common.